# How to automatically merge multiple CSVs from multiple sub-folders, without specifying sub-folder name?

Tags: python, loops, merge

I have a main folder of experiment with 2 condition folders in it. Condition 1 and Condition 2 folders both have 3 repetition folders in them and within these folders there is the final one of contact events containing a CSV file. How can I automatically merge all 3 CSV files from the repetition folders per condition, without specifying the path and assuming condition number? So far my code loops through all folders and combines all CSV files with the name contact_events.csv. The code is as follows:

```
    path = "C:\\Users\\victo\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\data\\"

    contact_csv = []

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path,filename)
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        for conditions in os.listdir(f):
            k = os.path.join(f,conditions)
            if os.path.isdir(k):
                for repetitions in os.listdir(k):
                    r = os.path.join(k, repetitions)
                    if os.path.isdir(r):
                        for contacts in os.listdir(r):
                            c = os.path.join(r, contacts)   
                            if os.path.isdir(c):
                                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(c, 'contact_events.csv')):
                                    df_results = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(c, 'contact_events.csv'))
                        contact_csv.append(df_results)
                        combined_csvs_for_conditions = pd.concat(contact_csv)       

combined_csvs_for_conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code to loop through the conditions and concatenate the files. To get a separated merge of the data files for each condition, you only need to move  the assignation `contact_csv = []` inside the loop of that condition.

Now, the real problem is how to store the result of each of this iterations, specially if we don't assume the number of conditions. We could use a list, but we would loose the identity of each dataframe (conditions are not necessarily goin to be read in alphabetical order).

So, we can use a dictionary and store each merge with the condition name as key.

```
conditons_data = {}

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path,filename)
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        for conditions in os.listdir(f):
            k = os.path.join(f,conditions)
            if os.path.isdir(k):
                
                # create a new container for the files of each condition
                contact_csv = []

                for repetitions in os.listdir(k):
                    r = os.path.join(k, repetitions)
                    if os.path.isdir(r):
                        for contacts in os.listdir(r):
                            c = os.path.join(r, contacts)   
                            if os.path.isdir(c):
                                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(c, 'contact_events.csv')):
                                    df_results = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(c, 'contact_events.csv'))
                            contact_csv.append(df_results)
                combined_csvs_for_conditions = pd.concat(contact_csv)
                
                # create an entry called as the current condition to stored the combined csvs
                conditons_data[conditions] = combined_csvs_for_conditions
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ignatius Reilly, I run your code, however the output was a CSV containing only 1 repetition CSV (aka it did not merge the 3csv in the condition folder)

Comment: I corrected the indentation in the last two lines of your original code. If it doesn't give you now the output you expected, please try to play a bit with the indentation of ` combined_csvs_for_conditions = pd.concat(contact_csv)` and the position of `contact_csv = []`, since it's difficult for me to debug without having your folder & files' structure in my computer. And tell me what worked so I can correct it! :)